# Adventures related to Sigil, the city of doors?

Tags: dnd-4e

Are there premade campaigns/adventures that take place at least partially in Sigil - City of Doors and where can I find them?

Comment: Do they have to be adventures with 4E stats, or will you accept adventures from older editions for conversion?

Comment: Al thou I would appreciate 4th edition ones, I am still interested in older ones as long as the concept of Sigil stays 4th ed (I am not sure if it has changed with editions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are interested in older stuff, here's the [list](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps.htm) of the official published adventures for *Planescape*:

- [2601 The Eternal Boundary](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-eternal.htm)
- [2604 Well of Worlds](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-well.htm)
- [2605 In the Abyss](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-abyss.htm)
- [2606 The Deva Spark](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-deva.htm)
- [2608 Fires of Dis](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-fires.htm)
- [2614 Harbinger House](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-harbing.htm)
- [2619 Something Wild](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-something.htm)
- [2626 Doors to the Unknown](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-doors.htm)
- [2628 The Great Modron March](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-modron.htm)
- [2629 Dead Gods](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-dead.htm)
- [2631 Tales From the Infinite Staircase](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-stair.htm)
- [2632 Faction War](http://www.tsrinfo.net/archive/ps/ps-faction.htm)

Don't know if 4ed changed the concept of Sigil, though, or if there is a fan conversion. The only conversion I know of is [for 3/3.5](http://www.planewalker.com/).

Comment: Sigil itself hasn't changed in 4E, but the planes around it have changed a great deal. Faction War is currently available from dndclassics.com and takes places entirely within Sigil. Tales from the Infinite Staircase is also available but the adventures will need altering to take place in domains in the Astral Sea.

Comment: Like @SimonGill said, a couple of them are available again from dndclassics, but I thought I should add that you're better off browsing the [Planescape](http://www.dndclassics.com/index.php?filters=0_44712_0&keywords=planescape) setting.

Answer (score 1):

Spoilers, of course.

Expedition on the Demonweb Pits is a planar campaign for D&D 3.5 featuring Sigil in its role of extraplanar crossroad.

The PCs arrive there after a poor hook they might entirely disregard and then they need to get in touch with severla NPCs living in Sigil.
A great part of the adventure happens in planes that can be reached from there but the quest-giver NPC lives in a inn in Sigil so the players will be back for restocking and talking to him quite often.
The book completely ignores factions, the lady of pain and any other planescape reference that I could recognize. Such a pity.

Answer (score 1):

The epic level adventure E1: Death's Reach from WotC has a (short) section based in Sigil

Comment: I would like to +1 because this is the only answer which mentions a 4e module. Yet E1 does not really have a section based in Sigil. You probably mean E2, right?